# Will collinearity be a problem for K-nearest neigbor?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multicollinearity

Should I concern about multicollinearity when building KNN model for the classification problem?

If yes. how to deal with it?

Comment: This would help, have a look


 : https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/8284/120788

Answer (score 5):

Clustering analysis is not negatively affected by heteroscedasticity but the results are negatively impacted by multicollinearity of features/ variables used in clustering as the correlated feature/ variable will carry extra weight on the distance calculation than desired.

Solution: Do not drop any variables, but you can use principal component analysis and consider principal component analysis results.

Comment: do you mean ”classification or cluster”.  Also, should I apply PCA first and then to build KNN?

Comment: The application of PCA first is a subject already in the literature. You are right.

Comment: I mean "classification and cluster".

Comment: @sycamore24, I did what have said. PCA then KNN. It becomes faster than before but the result is not better than KNN alone.

Comment: Can you try to use self Organizing map?